# text-to-speech using google API or AVspeech

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I need to use some kind of text-to-speech tool for pronouncing multiple languages. i've tried this code:

```
 AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
 AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init]autorelease];
[syn speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Which works fine, but since i want to use multiple languages it does not seem to have this function or what? How can i choose the language?

If the above is not possible i would like to use the Google api

How can i play this

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello

In my viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple and the definetely has the function, try the following:

```
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-gb"];
```

If you need to know all the languages avalible, put the following code somewhere:

```
NSArray* voices = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices];
NSLog(@"Voices: (%d) %@", voices.count, voices);
```

If you need further documentation on `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice` , then look at the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesisVoice_Ref/Reference/Reference.html